# Squarespace: Make 3 sibling elements have same height always and maintain responsive design

Tags: html, css, height, squarespace

I have been teaching myself front end web development for a while now and have taken on several client projects with good success so far.  I am currently working on the site www.thrivetech.com and having an issue.  There are 3 text columns with images above each on the home page of this site, and I cannot come up with a good way to make them all stay the same height.  At different screen widths these 3 columns change height and sometimes don't match.  Squarespace objects are natively responsive, and when the screen gets small enough these 3 columns stack on eachother and look fine.  I have added a lot of Custom CSS to change background colors, text colors, etc. but can't figure out how to make this work.  Even if I remove ALL CSS and just have a plain white page with black text, these columns still do this and don't stay the same height.  I have even contacted Squarespace support and they haven't come up with a solution.  See image below:

[image: Uneven column height]

I would include some CSS source, but it's best to navigate to the site at thrivetech.com and inspect the CSS to see what is going on.  I have considered doing something like using JS and jQuery to get the height of all 3 of these, determine which is the greatest, then set the height of all 3 to the greatest height, but it seems like there should be an easier, more elegant pure CSS solution??  Thanks for looking!

Comment: I tried using jQuery to get the heights of the 3 elements, then set the heights of all to the max height (the biggest of the 3).  This works to keep them all the same height, but the content inside overflows and is not visible :(

Comment: I have a bit of a wild idea to try to fix this: could we do something like use a for loop to increment the height of a div by 2-5px per iteration and make the condition of the loop check to see if the div has overflow=true??  In other words make the div just tall enough to show all content within it using a for loop and checking for overflow

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED:

I fixed the issue by using a media query to set the parent element of these 3 columns to display: flex; when the window is at least 640px wide.  The reason I need the media query is because they need to display as blocks when the window gets smaller so we can take advantage of Squarespace's native responsive design so the columns will stack on top of eachother on mobile and smaller screens.  Here's some simple pseudocode:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  #parentDiv { display: flex; } 
}
```